# Does an DB-First Entity context have to match the database schema, even for unused tables?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have an application that uses EF 5 and a database-first context which maps all the tables in a SQL Server 2008 database. Some of those tables are not used by my application. If I change the structure of an unused table, will it break my existing EF code?

I will update the `.edmx` to match the changed table soon (and yes I'll look into a bounded context too). I'm just curious to know if I *need* to do so, even when the table is entirely unused by my application.

Comment: No, if that table isn't referenced in your `.edmx` anywhere, then changing or even dropping it won't break your EF model.

Comment: Likewise, you can drop the table then go to your designer, right click and select update. Then refresh the models. Those that are still present [actively used] will remain, and the deprecated table will be removed.

Comment: @marc_s  Thanks for the comment.  To clarify, the changed tables are referenced in the .edmx- they're simply not used by the application code.  Can I leave it that way for a short time (until I have a chance to update the .edmx)?

Comment: @dcrobbins: you should be able to as long as there are no FK relationships/lazy loaded properties that will bomb out. I would just create a backup of the database, then either drop the table or simply empty them and run your tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you attempt to access the mismatched tables either by accessing it's `DbSet<T>` query or by access a navigation property to a `T` or `ICollection<T>` you will get a runtime exception. It will be some type of `System.Data.EntityException` (probably a `System.Data.MappingException`). The same thing will happen if you attempt to access a table that no longer exists.

It should not cause any exceptions until you access the mismatched/missing table.